# Query performance using ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I'm using coldfusion for a old project and I'm having issues with queries. I need to list all the units from my Units table and for each unit all the tenants payments. It was built using loop inside loop which makes very slow (code below):

```
    <!-- This query returns 511 Units -->
<cfquery name="getPropertyUnits" dataSource="rent">
    Select t.TenantID, u.UnitName
    From Units u
    INNER JOIN Tenants t on U.UnitID = t.UnitID
    Where u.Occupied = 1
    and u.PropertyID = 8
    and t.Prospect = 2
    Order By u.UnitName
</cfquery>

<!-- Loop the query getPropertyUnits -->
<cfloop query="getPropertyUnits">

    <!-- Each loop interaction, I get the transactions -->
    <!-- Just hard code date for testing -->
    <cfquery dataSource="rent" name="getTransactions">
            Select * From TenantTransactions
            Where TenantID = #TenantID#
            AND TenantTransactionDate BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-23'
            Order By TenantTransactionDate
    </cfquery>

    <!-- Loop the second query -->
    <cfloop query="getPropertyUnits">
        <!-- Work with data -->
    </cfloop>

</cfloop>
```

Is there a way to do just one query and get all the data?

Thanks

Comment: It just a simple join again. If you could do it once, you should be able to do it again.

Comment: Also, since you'll likely need joins in any web app, if you're unfamiliar with them, I'd suggest reviewing a tutorial. Here's one from a quick search https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join all three tables:

```
SELECT  t.TenantID, u.UnitName, tt.*
  FROM  Units u
        INNER JOIN Tenants t ON U.UnitID = t.UnitID
        LEFT JOIN TenantTransactions tt ON tt.tenantid = t.id
    AND tt.TenantTransactionDate BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-23'
  WHERE u.Occupied = 1
    AND u.PropertyID = 8
    AND t.Prospect = 2
  ORDER BY u.UnitName, tt.TenantTransactionDate
```

Keep in mind that the first two columns (`t.TenantID`, `u.UnitName`) will be repeated many times: one time per each row in the `TenantTransactions` table. You'll need to group them out in your application. Simple logic will do.

Anyway, this query is much faster than doing what you are doing now.

Also, if a tenant has no transactions, the values in the `tt.*` columns will all be null. Keep this in mind, since it uses a `left join`. This kind of join is necessary to ensure all tenants are shown, regardless of whether or not they have transactions.

Comment: Done. Please check it.